# Blob-triggered Azure Function doesn't process only one blob at a time anymore

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have written a blob-triggered function that uploads data on a CosmosDB database using the Gremlin API, using Azure Functions version 2.0. Whenever the function is triggered, it is going to read the blob, extract relevant information, and then queries the database to upload the data on it.

However, when all files are uploaded on the blob storage at the same time, the Function is going to process all files at the same time, which results in too many requests for the database to handle. To avoid this, I ensured that the Azure Function would only process one file at a time, by setting the `batchSize` to 1 in the `host.json` file :

```
{
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 1,
      "maxDequeueCount": 1,
      "newBatchThreshold": 0
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

This worked perfectly fine for 20 files at a time.

Now, we are trying to process 300 files at a time, and this feature doesn't seem to work anymore, the Function processes all the files at the same time again, which results in the database not being able to handle all the requests.

What am I missing here ? Is there some scaling issue I'm not aware of ?

Comment: Assuming it's a consumption plan it sounds like it spins up extra instances due to the queue of blobs being too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#hostjson-settings):

> If you want to avoid parallel execution for messages received on one queue, you can set batchSize to 1. However, this setting eliminates concurrency as long as your function app runs only on a single virtual machine (VM). If the function app scales out to multiple VMs, each VM could run one instance of each queue-triggered function.

You need to combine this with the app setting [WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_max_dynamic_application_scale_out) when you run in Consumption plan.

Or, according to the docs, the better way would be through the Function property functionAppScaleLimit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling#limit-scale-out

Comment: WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT made it, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` would work of course.

You can also scale to multiple Function App instances within one Host then you can have less hosts and more [`FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#functions_worker_process_count) per host. Cost implications would depend on your plan.

Note that all workers within a Host would share resources, so this is recommended for more IO bound workload.