# Blob Trigger Azure Function v1 failing to process only one blob at a time

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, blob, azure-blob-trigger

Here's all I've tried to try and stop the parallel processing:

1. host.JSON file looks like this:

```
"version": "2.0",
"extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "batchSize": 1,
      "maxDequeueCount": 1,
      "newBatchThreshold": 0
    }
```

2. I've scaled down my Function App through the portal:

[image]

3. I've added an Application Setting to my function app and set it to 1 `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT: 1`

[image]

4. Executed this statement with the proper credentials with Azure CLI:

```
az resource update --resource-type Microsoft.Web/sites -g <RESOURCE_GROUP> -n <FUNCTION_APP-NAME>/config/web --set properties.functionAppScaleLimit=<SCALE_LIMIT>
```

Even still, blobs that are uploaded the same time are processed at the same time. I would like to process the next blob only after the first one has finished. Anything else I could try?

Comment: You are using a blob triggered function but your host.json has the queue extension. Try using the blob extension and set the maxDegreeParallelism to 1.

Comment: @AnupamChand I'll try this first thing in the morning. Should I leave the queue extension as is and add the blob extension? Or just get rid of the queue extension while I try the blob extension? And just to make sure I have this correctly- it'd be `"extensions": { "blob": { "maxDegreeParallelism" : 1 }`

Comment: The queue extension will only impact if you are using queue triggered functions. I suggest removing it to avoid confusion. You can always add it again if needed.  {"version":"2.0", "extensions": { "blobs": { "maxDegreeParallelism" : 1 }}}. Yes, give it a shot and let us know how it goes.

Comment: @AnupamChand That's worked like a charm. Thanks so much! What's odd is I've seen so many people using the queue extension with their blob trigger, such  as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66368165/blob-triggered-azure-function-doesnt-process-only-one-blob-at-a-time-anymore) . In my mind it makes sense too because say blobs are uploaded at the same time- wouldn't they go into a queue of some sort to be processed?

Comment: That's great. Am hlad it works. Very strange what you say though. Even if blobs do use a queue in the background, the queue extension is only for queue triggers and the blob extension is for blob triggers. Else we wouldn't need 2 different extensions.

Comment: @AnupamChand Great to hear that the given solution working for OP. Post your solutions as an answer for the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a blob triggered function but your host.json has the queue extension. Try using the blob extension and set the maxDegreeParallelism to 1 as shown below.

The queue extension will only impact if you are using queue triggered functions. Even if blobs do use a queue in the background, the queue extension is only for queue triggers and the blob extension is for blob triggers. Else we wouldn't need 2 different extensions. I suggest removing the queue extension to avoid confusion. You can always add it again if needed. Your blob extension will look like this.

```
{"version":"2.0", "extensions": { "blobs": { "maxDegreeParallelism" : 1 }}}
```